Why can octave xlsread not read my xlsx file?
I just installed the io package of octave using
pkg install ~/octave/io-2.6.4.tar.gz

But when I now call xlsread from the octave prompt,
[numarr,txtarr,rawarr,limits] = xlsread('file_example_XLS_10.xlsx')

using the first example file from
https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-xls-download/
(after reformatting with Libre Office Calc to .xlsx) I get the following error:
error: cellfun: invalid function NAME: col2num 
error: called from 
    __OCT_xlsx2oct__ at line 210 column 12
    xls2oct at line 219 column 32 
    xlsread at line 384 column 32

What am I doing wrong?

The io package seems to not have been updated in many years. Try the fileio package: https://gnu-octave.github.io/packages/fileio/

The same issue was reported here (8 years ago): https://help.octave.narkive.com/2ZrC0rDS/problem-with-sheet-identifier-in-xls2oct -- The answer then was to re-install the io package.
